# Need to count the times a digit occurs in an excel column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is the situation- I have a column of equipment numbers, and the warehouse needs to order stickers to place on equipment in the field.  They order the stickers per letter or numeral, not a string of numbers (Like T, 1, 2, 3, rather than T123).

How can I count the number or times a "1" appears in my column in excel?  So far I have used countif(range, "asterisk1asterisk"), which returns the count of cells that contain a one, but many cells have multiple ones which are not included in count.  This will be so handy if I can figure it out, and I appreciate your help!  Thanks, -Tiffany

Answer (score 1):

If you have data in `A2:A100` then use this formula to count the number of 1s in that range

`=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(A2:A100)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A100,"1","")))`

That works because you compare the total lengths of the cells against the total lengths with the 1s replaced by nothing - that gives you the total number of 1s - you can do the same with "T" (but note, it's case-sensitive, so with "T" it counts only "T"s not "t"s)

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much!  And I appreciate the explanation, it makes sense.